# PHP str_replace: Element order in arrays and output result

Tags: php, str-replace

I am using str_replace() function to replace some values in array and use new value later in mysql query. However, I found a weird situation that I can't understand. Why these queries aren't returning the same output?

The first version of code returns: 214847

```
<php? $idPage=array(18,21,22);
$idCompetition=array(2147,2148,2149);

$idT=str_replace($idPage,$idCompetition,18);

echo $idT; ?>
```

And if I change the order in arrays, the result is: 2147

```
<php? $idPage=array(21,22,18);
$idCompetition=array(2148,2149,2147);


$idT=str_replace($idPage,$idCompetition,18);

echo $idT; ?>
```

The 2nd query returns the required result, and I used it in my code, but it's unclear to me why the first query isn't working correctly.

In real code I provide the subject of replacement (e.g. 18) by reading the global variable of page:

```
global $objPage;    
$idT=str_replace($idPage,$idCompetition,$objPage->id);
```

Thanks.

Comment: `<php?` Is this like a new PHP 7 opening tag?

Comment: In first query program does:
1. find 18 in string 18
2. change 18 to 2147.
3 after that find in  our string(2147) , 21 found and change to 2148, Our string is 214847

Comment: @Rizier123, lol... it is not as I know... I made mistake, and then copy-pasted it... :)

Comment: @darkoKc At least the syntax highlighting turned out very colorful.

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes, indeed it is colorful. Thank you for linking my question to that another one ("Trying to replace parts of string start with same search chars"), where I found the explanation how my code can be modified to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first code: 
str_replace finds first element of $idPage (== '18') in search string (== '18') and replaces it with '2147', then iterates to second value of $idPage (== '21'), finds it in search string (== '**21**47' atm) and replaces it with '2148', then iterates to third value of $idPage (== '22') and can't find it in search string (== '214847' atm).

Comment: Thank you. Your answer has explained what happened step by step. Technically, my question asked "Why I got 214847" and it was answered. In addition I want to mention that @Rizier123 has linked my question to another one where he explained how this problem can be avoided.